# Grouping data and Excluding Blanks from a Query Sort Function in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following Data set where I want to exclude the Blank cells from the Sort function, the formula I currently use has excluded the blanks from Col 3 but has given me the top 2 results in some outputs instead of the top 5.

Please see the Google sheet for your reference: the Tab "Data Tracking" is the source data, The tab Driver Baseline is the output, and The tab "Expected Outcome" is the output I am after.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MWlSh48FeTxdax8-SYyDU7nwEkD6t29xBzqB0JOrEoA/edit#gid=998858661

The formula I used:

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$D$326,2,true,3,false),IFERROR(row($B$3:$B$326)-match(query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$D$326,2,true,3,false),"Select Col2 "),query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"Select Col2"),0))},"Select Col2,Col1,Col3,Col4 where Col5<6 and Col3 is not NULL"))
```

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet link so that we can work on that.

Comment: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.` [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question must stand on its own. Please do not expect that users will/can/should open your spreadsheet in order to better understand you question. Any/all information relevant to your question needs to be included in the body of your question. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: `I want to exlude the Blank cells from the Sort funtion` You have supplied an example of your raw data and the result after your sort. Would you please edit your question to include an example of the expected output based on a successful sort.

Comment: I have added a spreadsheet and edited my question.

Comment: `I want to exclude the Blank cells from the Sort function`, `top 5`. Would you please describe the outcome that you are trying to achieve with this function.

Comment: its in the sheet

Comment: The outcome is in the sheet. What is the actual algorithm (in one or more  sentences)?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is an adaptation of [How to Find the Highest N Values in Each Group in Google Sheets](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-the-highest-n-values-in-each-group/#How_to_Change_the_Highest_2_Value_Rows_in_Each_Group_to_N_Value_Rows) ("infoinspired").

The processing sequence of the *infoinspired* formula is:

- sort the raw data
- rank the data
- report the data

Your have driver tracking information:
Col1 = Driver ID
Col2 = Subcontractor
Col3 = "Starting Week" as a percentage
Col4 = an additional code

Your goal is to:

- sort by Subcontractor (ascending), "Starting Week" descending
- ignore blank "Starting Week"

The challenges in applying this to your scenario include:

- your data starts on row 3; *infoinspired* starts on row 2
- your data includes blank cell values in three of four columns; *infoinspired* has no blanks

---

**SORTING DATA - Effect on blank cells**

- `SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false)`

  - Unlike `query`, `sort-true` (ascending results) will place blank values at the **bottom** of a list, BUT
  - the effect of the 2nd sort on Column C `sort-false` places the blank cells at the **top** of the list.

**Sample result - Jerusalem**

[image: OP sort]

The solution is to sort the results more than once:

- `sort(query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"select * order by Col2 asc, Col3 desc"),2,true,3,false)`

**Revised result - Jerusalem**

[image: Revised sort]

---

**RANKING - Effect of Row Numbers**

Ranking is achieved though a combination of combining "row number" and `match` index value. The first row number for each subcontractor **must** be the value of the "index plus 1". In the case of the first subcontractor, the index will = "1", so the first row **must** be "2".

*infoinspired* does this by starting their data on row 2 (`row(A2:A)`). But the OP data starts on row 3 (`row($B$3:$B$326)`). The solution is to deduct one from the row value:

- `arrayformula((row('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$A$326)-1))`

---

**REPORTING RESULTS - Blank Cells in Column C**

The OP notes that certain results didn't include 5 results:

- Iridium - three results
- Jerusalem - four results
- Sap Logistics - two results
- Sia Leela - four results

The reason for this is twofold:

- blank cells in Column C are removed (`Col3 is not NULL`) **after** ranking
- though `SORT` places blank cells in "sort column#1" at the bottom of the list, the blanks in "sort column#2" are placed at the top of the list.
- The effect is that records with blanks in Column C are ranked in the Top5, but then removed from the results.

The solution is to remove the blank records in Column C at the `SORT` stage.

---

**REPORTING - Top5: no Subcontractor (Column B)**

There are 22 records with no Subcontractor Name. Since ranking depends on matching the subcontractor name, the conventional formula does not find a match, and so reports all 22 records.

The solution is to derive and stack 2 sets of results.

- Set#1 - `Col2 is not null` - applies to all named subcontractors
- Set#2 - `Col2 is null` and `limit 5` - applies to blank subcontractors

---

**Modified Formula**

`=arrayformula(query({ query({sort(query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"select * order by Col2 asc, Col3 desc"),2,true,3,false), IFERROR((row('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$A$326)-1)-match(query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"select Col2"),query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"select Col2"),0))},"select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8 where Col2 is not null and Col9<6"); query({sort(query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"select * order by Col2 asc, Col3 desc"),2,true,3,false), IFERROR((row('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$A$326)-1)-match(query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"select Col2"),query(SORT('Data Tracking'!$A$3:$H$326,2,true,3,false),"select Col2"),0))},"select Col2, Col1, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8 where Col2 is null and Col9<6 limit 5")}))`

---

**Comparison to expected outcome**

[image: snapshot]